# How can I disable a region at with the context module at all pages but the <front> (home page)

Tags: 7

How can I disable a region at with the context module at all pages but the  (home page).

I've been trying to disable a region on all pages, except the , without having to write all the paths.
I can't make the wildcards `* ~` work on the `<front>` page.

In the condition field, I've tried to put alot of different combos i cant show here, because my post is deemed spam:

Imagine me using * ~ wildcards in front and in back of all the ways you can write the front page path: eks.  `http//www.domain.com/`
same goes for `<front>` with all the different combos.

Which one is supposed to work? Hope you get the idea.

Thanks!
Best Regards Elias
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Set `~<front>` in path. This will exclude only the front page.

I just tried it and it works properly.